# How do I to set selected value in a select option using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have two `select` and it has the same value, just changing the id. What I want is getting value selected in select one, and then select the same value in second select.

How could I do this ?

trying

```js
//here get the value select in select1 (it works)
var valueOfSelect1 = $('#select1 option:selected').val();

//select2 selected the value from select1
$('#select2 option[value=' + valueOfSelect1 + ']').prop('selected', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select1">
  <option value="AC">AC</option>
  <option value="SP">SP</option>
  <option value="RJ">RJ</option>
</select>

<select id="select2">
  <option value="AC">AC</option>
  <option value="SP">SP</option>
  <option value="RJ">RJ</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Could you please add a [mre]!?

Comment: You should be able to make a runnable snippet using some of the code here https://jsfiddle.net/taditdash/9Kfnt/

Comment: I don't see nay event handlers in your code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
// On select change
$('#select1').change(function() {
  
    // Get select1 value
    const val = this.value;
    
    // Apply value to select2
    $('#select2').val(val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select1">
    <option value="AC">AC</option>
    <option value="SP">SP</option>
    <option value="RJ">RJ</option>
</select>

<select id="select2">
    <option value="AC">AC</option>
    <option value="SP">SP</option>
    <option value="RJ">RJ</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This can be simplified by just saying $(‚#select2‘).val(val)